# SAS Macro Dereferencing

Tags: sas, macros

Following macro variables are declared:

```
%let x=2; 
%let y=3;
%let x3=4; 
%let y2=5; 
%let x2=6; 
%let y3=7; 
%let m=x; 
%let n=y;
```

What will following dereferencing evaluate to :

```
i.&&&m&y - &&&n&y 
ii.&&&m&x&&&n&y
```

Comment: What do you get when you run it?

Comment: 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 68         
 69         %let x=2;
 70         %let y=3;
 71         %let x3=4;
 72         %let y2=5;
 73         %let x2=6;
 74         %let y3=7;
 75         %let m=x;
 76         %let n=y;
 77         
 78         %put &&&m&y - &&&n&y ;
 4 - 7
 79         
 80         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 90

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: but not sure whether correct or not

Comment: What will following dereferencing evaluate to 
i. &&&m&y - &&&n&y 
ii. &&&m&x&&&n&y

Comment: It is what it is, so it is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can just run it to find the answer.

```
1    %let x=2;
2    %let y=3;
3    %let x3=4;
4    %let y2=5;
5    %let x2=6;
6    %let y3=7;
7    %let m=x;
8    %let n=y;
9
10   %put i. &&&m&y - &&&n&y ;
i. 4 - 7
11   %put ii. &&&m&x&&&n&y ;
ii. 67
```

When the macro processor sees && it translates it to & and leaves a reminder to itself that it will need to make another pass over the result to further resolve macro variable references.  So on the fist pass of &&&m&y it converts && to & and &m to x and &y to 3. Then when it goes back a processes the result it converts &x3 to 4.

You can turn on SYMBOLGEN and see it in action.

```
12
13   options symbolgen;
14   %put i. &&&m&y - &&&n&y ;
SYMBOLGEN:  && resolves to &.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable M resolves to x
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable Y resolves to 3
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable X3 resolves to 4
SYMBOLGEN:  && resolves to &.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable N resolves to y
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable Y resolves to 3
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable Y3 resolves to 7
i. 4 - 7
15   %put ii. &&&m&x&&&n&y ;
SYMBOLGEN:  && resolves to &.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable M resolves to x
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable X resolves to 2
SYMBOLGEN:  && resolves to &.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable N resolves to y
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable Y resolves to 3
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable X2 resolves to 6
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable Y3 resolves to 7
ii. 67
```